# Unhandled Rejection issue with React JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs

In a form I am building React 16, I was using a tutor to get some ideas and for my `componentDidMount` mock, the following code is throwing an error I don't understand or know how to resolve. I can still run the app, but curious why this is happening and how to resolve?

The code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('./fake_db.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                mbArea: data.mbArea,
                learningObjs: data.learningObjs,
                mbPhases: data.mbPhases,
                attendCount: data.attendCount,
                trainDate: data.trainDate,
                trainCoord: data.trainCoord,
                trainFormat: data.trainFormat,
                mbStat: data.mbStat,
                stakeHolders: data.stakeHolders,
                custType: data.custType,
                custDay: data.custDay,
                mbPartner: data.mbPartner,
                mbOther: data.mbOther
            });
        });
    }
```

And the error is:

[image]

Thoughts and input please?

Thanks much.

Comment: That error tells you that you are receiving something that isn't json. HTML often starts with `<`, so i'd assume your route is returning html.

Comment: check the network tab on developer console. you are not getting json from server

Comment: Try Console logging each then data passed in to make sure the data can be converted correctly

The error is pretty blatent that it is expecting a specific character but is reading the data incorrectly as a result you have to back track and observe the data difference and see where the error is, we don't ahve access to your backend.

Comment: Check the format of your json file it is highly likely the data passed to it does not match json format
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score -2):

Your .JSON file includes a ‘<‘ character

Your JSON file should be formatted as such:

```
{
    "key":"value"
}
```